# Test if perl cookie/value exists before calling "value" method

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

This works fine if a cookie already exists

```
use CGI::Cookie;
my %cookie = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
my $val = $cookie{'MY_COOKIE'}->value;
```

If there is no cookie, then the page failes with this error.

> Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at /file.cgi line 23.

This test generates the same error... presumably because it's trying to do the same thing

```
if ( $cookie{'MY_COOKIE'}->value ) {
  $val = $cookie{'MY_COOKIE'}->value;
}
```

How might I detect if there is no cookie or it has an empty value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
use CGI::Cookie;
my %cookie = CGI::Cookie->fetch;

my $myCookie = $cookie{'MY_COOKIE'};
my $val = defined($myCookie) ? $myCookie->value : '';
```

OR

```
if( defined( my $myCookie = $cookie{'MY_COOKIE'} )) {
   my $val = $myCookie->value;
   # ...
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also go for the shorter syntax `my $val = $myCookie->value // ''`

Comment: @ThomasLang $myCookie may be `undef`

Comment: Ah yes, my bad.

Comment: @AnFi. I've read many pages on cookies but either I never saw it or they don't mention copying out the specific cookie I'm after. And it did make me wonder. Anyway, I've added your change and suggested handling. Testing looks great! Thank you.

Comment: Being defined doesn't mean that it responds to method calls. This might work for this particular case, but in general this is not a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value that should be an object but might not be, you can wrap the call in `eval` to catch the error of calling a method on a non-object or undef value:

```
my $value = eval { $myCookie->value }; # maybe an object, maybe not
```

If `$myCookie` isn't an object or doesn't have a `value` method, `$value` gets undef and your program continues. As I recall, `CGI::Cookie` will not return an undef for a named cookie with no value; you'll get the (defined) empty string instead. So, if `$value` is any defined value, including any false value, there was a cookie with that name.

In your case, you might have the wrong name for the cookie, so you are looking from the wrong cookie. You can use `exists` to check for a key in a hash before proceeding:

```
if( exists $cookie{NAME} ) { ... }
```

But, that doesn't mean that the thing in `$cookie{NAME}` is the sort of object you expect. You might want to check that it can respond to that method name before proceeding:

```
if( exists $cookie{NAME} and $cookie{NAME}->can('value') ) { ... }
```

You can't merely check if the `$myCookie` is defined. You still don't know what's in it and your program blows up:

```
my $myCookie = 123;
if( defined $myCookie ) {
     $myCookie->value;  # still a fatal runtime error
     }
```

Comment: Nice work. Looks like I need to have a deeper look at 'defined' vs 'eval' vs 'exists' but that's okay because they're exactly the sort of things I need to brush up on. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.